# Multiplicate two fields from different columns - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following two tables:

............................................

Product  | Game  | Quantity

1------------2-----------3

1------------3-----------3

............................................

GameID | Price

2--------------5

3--------------8

...........................................

How can I multiply quantity * price for each game using a WHERE or something similar (as I want to get the total cost for Product 1, for example) in MS Access? Game is a foreign key to GameID which is a primary key.
I know it's with JOINS but I can't make it work.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Are you looking for solution in MS Access or SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a `JOIN` between the tables like below. See [Documentation For more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
select p.Product,
p.Game,
p.Quantity * q.Price as calculated_column
from Producttab p
inner join gametab q on p.Game = q.GameID
where p.Product = 3;
```

Looks like it's complaining about those table alises. Here is MS-Access Version:

```
select Producttab.Product,
Producttab.Game,
Producttab.Quantity * gametab.Price as calculated_column
from Producttab
inner join gametab on Producttab.Game = gametab.GameID
where Producttab.Product = 3;
```

Comment: and how can i filter by the product I want?, I mean, that would do that for all products, not the one I only need

Comment: @Wrong, include a `WHERE` condition. See edit in answer.

Comment: @Wrong, see edit in answer again. Do some reading and research and learn on the way.

Comment: how could I expand it 3 tables? I mean. I have tables A, B and C. A is related to B and B to C. And I want to relate A to C